# nAnt running .bat with folderPath as parameter

Tags: batch-file, nant

I am trying to setup a nAnt task to run a batch file with 4 parameters. First 2 parameters are folder path, so it required to be wrapped with double quote. Here's my build file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Proejct" default="dbsetup" >
  <description>nAnt script</description>

  <property name="project.SQLBinFolder" value='"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\"' />
  <property name="project.SQLDataFolder" value='"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\"' />
  <property name="project.DBServerName" value="JJADEJA-VISTA-P\SQLEXPRESS" />
  <property name="project.DatabaseName" value="dbMain" />

  <target name="test">
    <echo message="..\Database\RunDBSQL.bat ${project.SQLBinFolder} ${project.SQLDataFolder} ${project.DBServerName} ${project.DatabaseName}" />
  </target>

  <target name="dbsetup" description="Setup database script">
    <exec program="..\Database\RunDBSQL.bat" >
      <arg value="${project.SQLBinFolder}" />
      <arg value="${project.SQLDataFolder}" />
      <arg value="${project.DBServerName}" />
      <arg value="${project.DatabaseName}" />
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

my test target outputs

```
..\Database\RunDBSQL.bat "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\dbCIMA" JJADEJA-VISTA-P\SQLEXPRESS dbCIMA
```

which is works fine from command line.

When I run dbsetup target, it gives me following error.

```
dbsetup:

     [exec] Files\Microsoft was unexpected at this time.

BUILD FAILED - 0 non-fatal error(s), 1 warning(s)

c:\Projects\CIMA\Trunk\Solution file\CIMA.build(15,6):
External Program Failed: c:\Projects\CIMA\Trunk\Database\RunDBSQL.bat (return co
de was 255)

Total time: 0.1 seconds.
```

My RunDBSQL.bat

```
SET SQLBinFolder="%1"
SET SQLDataFolder="%2"
SET DBServerName=%3
SET DatabaseName=%4

SET PATH="%1%"

cls
echo.
echo *****************************
echo * Database build and update *
echo *****************************
echo.

echo SQLCmd Exe Path : %SQLBinFolder%
echo SQL Data Folder Path : %SQLDataFolder%
echo Database server: %DBServerName%
echo Database name  : %DatabaseName%
echo.
```

I trying wrapping my variables and property in all kind of combination of wrapping / escaping, but no luck. Anyone has got any suggestion or idea, please let me know.

Thanks In advance,
Jay

Comment: ... just curious: Have you tried the corrected suggestion? Does it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the edit history of this answer, you will see how terribly wrong my first guess was. You rather need less than more quotes. An `arg` node's `value` attribute is quoted automatically if it's a path containing whitespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Proejct" default="dbsetup" >
  <description>nAnt script</description>
  <property name="project.SQLBinFolder" value="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\" />
  <property name="project.SQLDataFolder" value="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\" />
  <property name="project.DBServerName" value="JJADEJA-VISTA-P\SQLEXPRESS" />
  <property name="project.DatabaseName" value="dbMain" />
  ...
  <target name="dbsetup" description="Setup database script">
    <exec program="..\Database\RunDBSQL.bat" >
      <arg value="${project.SQLBinFolder}" />
      <arg value="${project.SQLDataFolder}" />
      <arg value="${project.DBServerName}" />
      <arg value="${project.DatabaseName}" />
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

RunDBSQL.bat: Remove quotes here. Arguments passed by NAnt will be qouted appropriately.

```
SET SQLBinFolder=%1
SET SQLDataFolder=%2
SET DBServerName=%3
SET DatabaseName=%4
...
```

**CAVEAT**: NAnt's automatic quoting facility doesn't work if the argument's value is combined from a command-line switch and a path containing whitespace. Example:

```
<property name="bar.path" value="C:\Program Files\bar" />
<exec program="foo.bat" >
  <arg value="-f:${bar.path}" />
</exec>
```

This is what I had in mind when I suggested explicit quoting:

```
<property name="bar.path" value="C:\Program Files\bar" />
<exec program="foo.bat" >
  <arg value="-f:&quot;${bar.path}&quot;" />
</exec>
```

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. Even after trying different option I get either to script to work (but it seems to be passing parameters without quotes). or give the same error.

Comment: You're right, Jay. I updated my answer (well, it's more a complete rewrite than an update). This should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will work if you encode the double quotes with `&quot;`